# My Website doesn't "see" any of the Jquery I'm writing, even the most simple functions

Tags: jquery, web, html, web-hosting

I use a localhost and godaddy server. I have all of my files linked and in the right place. my jquery is in a script.js file in my javascripts folder in the same directory as my index.php file. this is the  link i have in my header, which is included at the beginning of loading every page on my website.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not even sure if the library is necessary but I added it to repel any dumb suggestions. why would neither my localhost or live website be recognizing the jquery?

for a simple example. 
I have in my script.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#jscriptprac').mouseenter(function(){
$(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$('#jscriptprac').mouseleave(function(){
$(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.25);
});
});
```

where I'm just changing the opacity but it wont change, ive also altered my .css file to make sure id see the change if it in fact changed, along with hundreds of other simple jquery functions with no success in making any dynamic changes to the webpage.

and the html

```
 <div id="jscriptprac">text</div>
```

extremelyyyyy simple.

normally I don't even write text in html because every bit of content on my website is loaded from my database and i manage it with a cms i built. but this is the simplest way to describe my problem.

anyone have ideas on why my website refuses to execute jquery events/handlers/functions?

Comment: id like to add that i added styling to the div like width height and opacity, its not just the word text

Comment: check the browsers dev tools to make sure that it's downloading the jquery file when you load the website...otherwise your link may not be correct.

Comment: prophecy is yet to  come. Post a link to your site

Comment: Check if over here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/gGVh8/

Comment: @Adil, the problem is clearly not the specific code, but that JQuery is not running at all

Comment: thanks for the site Adil, definitely adding it to my favorites, I checked it there, it works there, my jquery is perfect, its just the index.php isnt seeing it.

Comment: Ok, here's a simple test. Just go to your website. Open the console and press `$` and then enter and see the output. Does it returns a function(). That means your site includes the jQuery files files, otherwise not!

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this script.js:13
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: well if jqueryisn't defined,you might be loading it more than once which could cause issues. Or perhaps youre also using another javascript library on the page that uses the '$' selector?

Comment: that jquery function is the only one on the entire site, the rest are commented out to troubleshoot. but ill look into it loading more than needed as a problem, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dont think jquery-ui includes jquery itself. Youd need a second script tag for jquery itself BEFORE ui:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: should I add the actual version where VERSION is? I added <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/VERSION/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  is the only error i get now thanks prodigitalson that narrows it down a lot, i had few errors.

Comment: @codey: well thats a big one.. that means jquery isnt loaded when you try to execute your code. You do have the tag linking to `script.js` somewhere AFTER the jquery lib tags, correct?

Comment: its codeybuzz.com it works now i just have to look into managing many jquery functions just i just learned jscript and starting jquery.

Comment: Codey nettuts has a great 30 day tutorial on jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try doing basic debugging techniques.

At the first line of your `script.js` put in a simple `alert('script.js is loaded');`  (if you are familiar with the console, it's less obnoxious if you replace calls to `alert` with calls to `console.log`).  If you see that, then your script is being loaded correctly.  If not figure out why its not -- e.g., view the source code in chrome and see if you can click and see the text of the JS file.

If you saw the message, next check to see if jquery is loaded?  Try something like `var jquery_ver = $.fn.jquery; alert("I am running jquery:" jquery_ver)` at the top of your script.  Do you see that message?  If not jquery isn't loaded, so you need to load jquery with something like:

```
 <script src="/path/to/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or from [google's CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: yea i am familiar with the console, thanks i'll use this technique from now on.